# What are few techniques that use sequential pattern mining for predicting location?

Tags: data-mining, sequential-analysis

I found many sequential pattern techniques like

1. GSP Algorithm
2. Sequential PАttern Discovery using Equivalence classes (SPADE)
3. Apriori algorithm  etc

But they all work for data with certainty like shopping items, 0's and 1's etc.

Is there a good technique with which I can use sequential pattern mining to find uncertain data like location.

For example my learning data contains huge data containing (latitude,longitude, time)